# Лебедь — царевна, а кто царь?

Tags: литература

И снова я с вопросом о Царевне Лебедь. Просто, вот задумалась над ее образом, и много непонятностей всплыло. Например, если она — царевна, то кто царь и ее отец? Об этом никогда нигде не упоминалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А когда был первый вопрос???

За вопрос - спасибо. Давно не было повода взглянуть на любимую "Сказку..." с нового ракурса. Там, понятно, царевна - переносно. Ну или отвлеченно. Напоминает внешне или манерами. Но с другой сторона, она ведь и превращается в настоящую царевну...

Навскидку  - не помню, чтобы в черновиках и набросках у Пушкина этот момент проскакивал.  Хотя, если сравнить его первую запись "первоисточника" любой сказки или предания и окончательный вариант - можно и не узнать...

//-------------------

Ну, в общем, более или менее понятно.
Очень кратко, очень уж хочется "идею застолбить", а времени нету.
Надеюсь, что когда-нибудь срастется написать и поподробнее.

Судя по всему царевна Лебедь - персонаж весьма не простой.
С одной стороны подобно царевне Лягушке - действительно образ отвлеченный, но это отдельный разговор. Народные корни вполне прослеживаются, папы ей не требуется, он - "виртуальный".

С другой же стороны её можно рассматривать как воплощение Добра в извечном его противостоянии со Злом. 
Сергей Трухтин (http://www.proza.ru/2007/05/28-276) подсказал мне эту зацепку. У Пушкина есть строчка "вот что чудом-то зовут". Чудо здесь то, что создано Богом. Царевна наполняет безликий город на безлюдном острове чудесами, по наущению... Зла. Бабариха с двумя домработницами - Зло, Дьявол. Добро ***реализует*** задуманное Злом. "Я — часть той силы, что вечно хочет зла и вечно совершает благо". Круг замкнулся Потрясающая интерпретация главной схватки мироздания.

Чудо это творится только по Божественному провидению. "Отец" царевны - Создатель. Не совсем, конечно, христианский, лубочно-народный, но оно и понятно.

Я пока не вижу слабых мест у такой версии.

Еще раз огромное спасибо за вопрос.

А где, кстати, был первый? 
(нашел, ответил)

Comment: а вот тут: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/20940/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82

Answer (score 1):

Упоминаний в сказке нет, соответственно и ответа на ваш вопрос тоже.

Если менее конкретно, то в русском свадебном обряде "царевной" величают любую невесту независимо от сословия. И "царевна" тут говорит о том, что девушка на выданье, а не замужем за каким-либо царём.

Comment: Как упоминаний Вам надобно?

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что в сказке есть упоминания об отце царевны лебеди?

Comment: Переведите на русский свой первый комментарий.

>Как упоминаний Вам надобно?

Я перевёл первое слово как "каких" поэтому и указал какие упоминания нужны для точного ответа на вопрос. Потому что для того что бы найти узнать "как?" нужно хотя бы иметь "что?".

Comment: Всё. Считайте, что Вам удалась меня затроллить.
Дальше простите, без - меня.